# How does the proportion of X > a compare to the proportion of Y > a?

Tags: self-study, distributions

I am completing CS109 Data Science class available online for free. I'm not quite sure what they are asking for.

> In general, if group A has larger values than group B on average, does this
>       mean the largest values are from group A?
>
> Assume you have two list of numbers, X and Y, with distribution
>       approximately normal. X and Y have standard deviation equal to 1, but the 
>       average of X is different from the average of Y. If the difference in the
>       average of X and the average of Y is larger than 0, how does the proportion 
>       of X > a compare to the proportion of Y > a?

What proportion are they talking about here:

> of X > a compare to the proportion of Y > a?

What do I need to discover?

Thank you.

Comment: Likely the proportion of numbers in each list.

Comment: Welcome to the site, solarguard! For this kind of question, we ask that you [read the self-study guidelines](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), and edit your post to add that tag.

Answer (score 3):

The distributions are supposed to look similar, because we are told they are "approximately normal" and both have the same standard deviation.  The one with larger mean ($\mu_A$, the average of $X$) therefore has been shifted to the right, just like the blue density curve (representing a histogram) relative to the red one in this figure (whose mean is $\mu_B$, the average of $Y$).

[image: Figure]

This should make it obvious that there is more area under the blue (right-hand) curve to the right of any given value $a$ compared to the area under the red (left-hand) curve.  The difference in areas is that of the shaded region.  Since areas represent proportions (the total area under either of these curves is $100\%$), the shaded area represents *how much greater* the proportion is in group $A$ compared to group $B$.

Comment: @ Whuber: The probability of the shaded area can be calculated by converting both distributions to standard normal.

Comment: @Subra No, it cannot, because when that happens both distributions will be *identical* and the shaded area will be zero.  That's what Dougal was trying to tell you in a comment to your answer.

Comment: @ Whuber: No they wont be same. Because the mean is different for x and y distributions. point 'a' in X and point 'a' in Y  will lead to different points in a standard normal distribution. (use the Z equation you will see this)

Comment: @subra Then you are not writing what you mean.  The "standard normal" is a *unique* distribution with zero mean and unit variance.  It should go without saying, and I'm sorry for having to repeat this, but when you call for "converting both distributions to standard normal" you have incontrovertibly and clearly made those distributions identical.

Comment: @ Whuber: Yes "standard normal" is a unique distribution.  The truth is any normal distribution can be converted into a standard normal distribution.The point here is the z value in standard normal will refer to different points in the original distributions (X and Y). Bcos the original distributions X and Y are different in mean. The upshot here is converting different normal distributions into standard normal does not make them equal. You need convergence in CDF for distributions to be equal.

Comment: I'm sorry, that is such a singular (and incorrect) statement that I don't even know how to reply, so I won't.  Let's just leave it at that.

Comment: You can take this statement to any statistician and verify, and I will stop at that point.

Answer (score -2):

Whenever you have to compare two different normal distributions, you have to convert both to Standard Normal Distributions. That way both distributions are in the same scale:

for X Distribution:

Convert a into standard normal (Z value) = `(a-X̅)/1= a-X̅`

```
Pr (X>a) = 1 -Pr (Z<( a-X̅))
```

Similarly for Y distribution:

```
Pr (Y>a) = 1 -Pr (Z<( a-Y̅))
```

Now your original question is difference in proportions:

`Pr (X>a) - Pr (Y>a) (Or Vice Versa)`

Which is equivalent to=

```
= [1 -Pr (Z<( a-X̅))] – [1 -Pr (Z<( a-Y̅))] 
=  [Pr (Z<( a-X̅))] – [Pr (Z<( a-Y̅))]                        
=  Pr (Z<( a-X̅-a+Y̅)
=  Pr (Z<( Y̅-X̅))
```

Since Z is Symmetric: `Pr (Z<( Y̅-X̅)) = Pr (Z<( X̅-Y̅))`
This you can read directly from the Z table

Comment: I don't see any reason to standardize here,,,,

Comment: @ Dougal: We need to convert them to standard normal. Because the mean is different for X and Y distributions. point 'a' in X and point 'a' in Y will lead to different points in a standard normal distribution. (use the Z equation you will see this). Then  we can use the Z table to read the probabilities.